# How to write the start address of a section to a dedicated location in ROM

Tags: ld, bare-metal

In a bare metal project, I need to write the start address of the ROM section to a dedicated address. What I've found so far is something like this definition in the linker script:

```
MEMORY{
    ROM  (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x00018000, LENGTH = 0x8000
    UICR (r)   : ORIGIN = 0x10001000, LENGTH = 0x400
}

SECTIONS {
    .bootloader_addr 0x10001014 :
    {
        KEEP(*(.bootloader_addr))
    } > UICR
}
```

and to define the value that is to be placed at 0x10001014 I could add this somewhere in a C++ file:

```
std::uint32_t uicr_bootloader_start_address 
    __attribute__((section(".bootloader_addr"),used)) = 
        0x18000;
```

Does someone have an idea how I could avoid having to declare the constant integer and to use the linker to directly write the startadress of the code section to `0x10001014`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used this myself, but `ld` supports a [`LONG(expr)` command](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Output-Section-Data.html#Output-Section-Data) that should insert a 4-byte literal into the binary.

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm. No I have to figure out, how to evaluate the start address of the ROM MEMORY, so I don't have to copy the start address.

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki I think you should be able to do it by putting just a symbol `rom_start_address` in the `ROM` region, then `LONG(rom_start_address)`?

Comment: I will try that tomorrow and report if that worked. I've tried something like LONG(ADDR(ROM))

Comment: Yeah I thought `LONG(ADDR(ROM))` would work but [memory regions are a different namespace](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_16.html).

Comment: The error message one gets when using `LONG(ADDR(ROM))`is `invalid data statement`. Your proposed solution to use an extra symbol works perfectly. Thank you very much.